# Can't import QtCore from PyQt5 python 3.x

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.6, qtcore

I'm trying to build a GUI for my python application, but I'm having trouble with pyqt5 everytime I try to execute the following command

```
pyuic5 gui.ui -o gui.py
```

I get the following error

> from PyQt5 import QtCore
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

I tried to import QtCore from PyQt5 using python3.6 but I got the following error as well:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Ps: import PyQt5 is successful:

```
import PyQt5
```

any help?

Comment: How have you installed PyQt5?

Comment: ofcourse I did using **pip install PyQt5**

Comment: I even tried uninstalling PyQt5 and re installing it but it didn't work. @eyllanesc

Comment: I Have exactly this problem. I am suspecting python 3.6 as it works fine on another machine (linux) but not on this one (windows7). I have heard somthing about a 'roulette' file?